# Density function of the max of smallest and largest observation

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, order-statistics

Consider $n$ independent uniform random variables $X_i \sim U(-\theta,\theta)$, and
let $Y_1 = \min(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ and $Y_n = \max(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ .

What is distribution of $Z = \max (-Y_1,Y_n)$, given that the joint PDF of $Y_1$ and $Y_n$ is 
$$
f(y_1, y_n) = \frac{n(n-1)}{(2θ)^n} (y_n-y_1)^{n-2} , \quad  -\theta < y_1 < y_n < \theta ?
$$

Comment: Please double-check your equation for the joint PDF: what are you doing subtracting $\theta$ from it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Likelihood Ratio of two-sample Uniform Distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81225/likelihood-ratio-of-two-sample-uniform-distribution)

Comment: The easy way to do this would be to look at $|Y|$ so you're back to a simple max problem $Z=max |Y_i|$.

Comment: Nice problem. _Prima facie_, it _seems_ attractive to treat it, by symmetry, as the max of two separate univariate problems, or equivalently, as the pdf of the sample maximum given the parent $Uniform(-\theta, \theta)$ with sample size $2n$... but that will yield an incorrect solution, because it misses the crucial interdependency. And the interdependency is that the domain of support for $Z = max(-Y_1,Y_n)$ is not $(-\theta, \theta)$, but rather $(0,\theta)$, because (i) if $y_n > 0$, then $Z > 0$, and (ii) if $y_n < 0$, then $y_1 < 0$ ---> $Z>0$. The pdf of $Z$ is a Power Function.

Comment: First find the CDF of $Z$ as is done in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/164656/119261) answer.