# Most Powerful Lower Tail Test for Uniform Distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, statistical-power, uniform-distribution

**Problem Statement:** Let $Y_1, Y_2,\dots,Y_n$ denote a random sample from a uniform
distribution over the interval $(0,\theta).$ Find a most powerful $\alpha$-level test for testing $H_0:\theta=\theta_0$ against $H_a:\theta=\theta_a,$ where $\theta_a<\theta_0.$

First Note: This is Exercise 10.85**a** in *Mathematical Statistics with Applications, 5th Ed.,* by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Sheaffer.

Second Note: This question has been asked several times before, notably [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/475652/most-powerful-test-of-size-zero-for-theta-given-random-sample-from-u0-the/475663?noredirect=1#comment992665_475663) (not the same test direction as mine, which is important), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/379509/most-powerful-test-of-simple-vs-simple-in-mathrmunif0-theta#379539) (also reversed direction), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117844/ump-for-u0-theta-simple-x-simple-hypothesis?rq=1) (same direction as mine). [This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515260/critical-region-for-an-uniform-distribution) uses the LRT, which I have not yet reached in the book. So why clutter up Stats.SE with another question? For several reasons: 1. Because no solution in any of those links has enough steps worked out for my understanding. In particular, expressions such as $\sqrt[n]{\alpha}$ or $\sqrt[n]{1-\alpha}$ appear without much explanation. I have interacted with a number of the solution authors, but my thick skull simply hasn't been able to grasp what's really going on. I know this is a self-study question, but I have spent literally days on it, and I need some step-by-step help with this, all spelled out. 2. I find the $\phi$ notation clutters things up considerably, and I would rather have a solution that does not utilize the $\phi$ notation for a test.

**My Work So Far:** I use the notation $Y_{(i)}$ for the $i$th order statistic. The fundamental distribution function is
$$f(y|\theta)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac1\theta,&0<y<\theta\\
0,&\text{elsewhere}.
\end{cases}
$$
Hence, the likelihood function is
$$L(\theta)=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{\theta^n},&0<Y_{(1)}\le Y_{(n)}<\theta\\
0,&\text{elsewhere}.
\end{cases}$$
Then we have
\begin{align*}
L(\theta_0)&=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{\theta_0^n},&0<Y_{(1)}\le Y_{(n)}<\theta_0\\
0,&\text{elsewhere},
\end{cases}\\
L(\theta_a)
&=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{\theta_a^n},&0<Y_{(1)}\le Y_{(n)}<\theta_a\\
0,&\text{elsewhere}.
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
We recall the assumption that $\theta_a<\theta_0.$ It follows that if
$L(\theta_a)\not=0,$ then $L(\theta_0)\not=0.$ Hence,
$$\frac{L(\theta_0)}{L(\theta_a)}=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\theta_a^n}{\theta_0^n},&0<Y_{(1)}\le Y_{(n)}<\theta_a<\theta_0\\
\text{undefined},&\text{elsewhere.}
\end{cases}
$$
From this information, we discover that the Neyman-Pearson Lemma Inequality
can only be satisfied if $Y_{(n)}<\theta_a.$ That is, we would accept the
alternative hypothesis if $Y_{(n)}<\theta_a,$ and reject it if
$\theta_a<Y_{(n)}.$

**My Questions:**

1. Is my reasoning correct so far? If not, why not?
2. Is this an $\alpha$-level test? If not, why not and how can I adjust it (please spell this out in detail!) so that it is an $\alpha$-level test? What is the general principle being used to convert it to an $\alpha$-level test?
3. I note that $Y_{(n)}$ is a biased estimator for $\theta,$ while $(n+1)Y_{(n)}/n$ is unbiased. Does this matter at all in this question? Why or why not?
4. If $\theta_a<Y_{(n)}<\theta_0,$ doesn't $L(\theta_a)=0?$ And so the Neyman-Pearson fraction would be undefined, correct?
5. If we were to change the problem so that $\theta_a>\theta_0,$ what would change in the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your reasoning seems right to me.
2. Rejecting simply if $Y_{(n)}<\theta_a$ is not an $\alpha$-level test.  For that we would need to look at the sampling distribution of the sample maximum.  Under $H_0$ the sample maximum of $n$ uniform random variables has CDF

$$F_{Y_{(n)}}(y_{(n)})=\Big(\frac{y_{(n)}}{\theta_0}\Big)^n$$

2. For an $\alpha$-level test we can reject $H_0$ when $y_{(n)}<\theta_a$ and $\Big(\frac{y_{(n)}}{\theta_0}\Big)^n\le \alpha$.
3. The unbiased estimator is not needed to construct a test, but it is useful to have.
4. I believe so, but then there is nothing to test since $\theta_a<y_{(n)}$ is irrefutible evidence that $H_a$ is false.
5. If we change the problem so that $\theta_a>\theta_0$ then we would reject $H_0$ if $y_{(n)}>\theta_0$ since this is irrefutible evidence that $\theta>\theta_0$.  If $\theta_a>\theta_0>y_{(n)}$ I'm not sure there is an obvious way to construct an $\alpha$-level test.  We might be forced to use the larger value as the null value and smaller value as the alternative value.  I haven't yet read your references so perhaps they have a different answer for this.

Let me know if I have made any mistakes.

Comment: I'm reading your answer over and over - it's pretty packed. Question about 5: why wouldn't we reject $H_0$ if $y_{(n)}>\theta_a>\theta_0?$ It seems asymmetric with the $\theta_a<\theta_0$ problem.

Comment: Regarding 2: I think I've finally got my brain wrapped around this, thanks! To test my understanding: we reject $H_0$ if and only if $y_{(n)}\le\min(\theta_0\alpha^{1/n},\theta_a).$ Is that correct?

Comment: One last question: is this test unique? How would we know either way?

Comment: Regarding 5: We would indeed reject $H_0$ if $y_{(n)}>\theta_a>\theta_0$ since $y_{(n)}>\theta_0$ is irrefutable evidence that $\theta>\theta_0$.  Regarding 2: yes.  Can you elaborate more on the test being unique?

Comment: Yeah, I think I figured out why we don't REQUIRE $y_{(n)}>\theta_a$ to reject $H_0.$ It has to do with the asymmetry inherent in the problem: the $y_i$'s all tend to be to the left, not to the right. Plus, the way the likelihood ratio behaves when $y_{(n)}>\theta_0.$ Regarding uniqueness: is there another $\alpha$-level test that is as powerful as this one?

Comment: To determine if this is the most powerful test we would need to consult the Neyman-Pearson lemma.  My intuition tells me it is the most powerful test since the likelihood ratio is a function of $Y_{(n)}$, we have its exact sampling distribution, and this appears to be sufficient for estimating $\theta$ (there is no other information in the likelihood that could be used for estimating $\theta$).

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, Geoffrey! I greatly appreciate it!